# Android UI images memory issue

Tags: android, performance, android-resources, android-bitmap

I'm building an application with very big sized images.

Almost all of my UI components are made of ImageViews.

I only have to show 12 images(ui components) on my first activity, but it consumes 80mb on startup.

The images are divided into each drawable directories using Android Drawable Importer.

By doing this I was able to reduce the runtime memory(which I can see on the Android studio's device monitor) to half, but it is still consuming 80~120mb of memories, which I believe is too much.

**The first question is, isn't 80~120mb too much for a four screen(two activities, three fragments) application?**

The second is, if it's too much then, **what and how can I do to reduce memory usage?**

Comment: how about using image loader library like Glide? Glide is very good in memory management when displaying image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with images keep in mind that there is a HUGE difference between compressed format (jpg, png..) and Bitmap. Computing the size of a Bitmap is pretty easy, it's width * height * 4 bytes (assuming that the bitmap has the default configuration argb888). So a full hd image that compressed is xy kb, when decompressed will occupy 8294400 bytes (~8mb). So my advice to reduce memory consumption is... scale down your images.
 You're asking if 80-120 mb is too much, well it seems like a lot but it really depends on what you're doing. What happen if you force garbage collection (there should be an icon in the device monitor)?
Another thing to take into account is how to decompress the images, refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and use a library (Picasso, Glide..).